# Reading the share count of a Facebook post from Graph API or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to get the share count of a post (that is NOT mine nor my pages) that I can see on my timeline. I can see the share count on my timeline, but when I open Graph API explorer (my token has read_stream permission) and request `select share_count, share_info from stream where post_id = POST_ID_OF_THE_POST`, I am getting nothing:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I've also tried the non-FQL way: `graph.facebook.com/POST_ID` but it doesn't return anythinh related to shares (it has all the data, comments, likes, but no shares).

How can I get the share count of any post that I can see?